# What is the Query language for OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I am building an OrientDB system which needs access to the OrientDB query language, much like Cypher is for Neo4j. I can't find any documentation for this however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have their github repo here:
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb

And the database related documentation here:
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL